# Add a recurring and one-time fee to a subscription

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Our users need to be able to activate addons on their account, which will cost a 1 time setup fee (say $100) and then a recurring monthly fee after that (say $10). I can do this manually by going to the Stripe Dashboard, finding the subscription, and adding both these items (the one time $100 and the recurring $10) and clicking "Update". However, when I change my code:

```
    $subscription->swapAndInvoice([
        'site-membership', // all users already have this plan

        '10-monthly-fee',  // this is the addon being added
        '100-one-time-fee' // one-time addon fee
    ]);
```

I get an error:

> **Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException:**
> You passed a non-recurring price but this field only accepts recurring prices.

If I can't use `swap`, is there some other way I can do this all at once? I know I could make an independent invoice for the one time fee, but I would hate for our customers to receive two separate invoices when they could just be invoiced once for $110. Is this possible using Cashier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no method in Cashier directly, but I found a way to achieve this by passing a value through to Stripe. ([Stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-add_invoice_items))

```
    $subscription->swapAndInvoice([
        'site-membership',
        '10-monthly-fee'
    ], [
        'add_invoice_items' => [
            [ 'price' => '100-one-time-fee' ]
        ]
    ]);
```